# Is there a way to split a string on delimiters including colon(:) except when it involves time?

Tags: python, regex, string, split, python-re

I am trying to split the string below on a number of delimiters including \n, comma(,), and colon(:) except when the colon is part of a time value. Below is my string:

```
values = 'City:hell\nCountry:rome\nUpdate date: 2022-09-26 00:00:00'
```

I have tried:

```
result = re.split(':|,|\n', values)
```

However, this ends up splitting the time resulting in `

```
['City','hell','Country','rome','Update date',' 2022-09-26 00','00','00']
```

Whereas the expected outcome is

```
['City','hell','Country','rome','Update date', '2022-09-26 00:00:00']
```

Any help/assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Not a python user but maybe PCRE verbs with https://pypi.org/project/regex/? e.g. https://regex101.com/r/qEL99r/1

Comment: Use regex replace on all actual time sequences to change the colon delimiter to a different character.  Then do your split.  Then do a string replace to replace your character back to colon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use look-behind to ensure that what is before : is not a pair of digits

```py
re.split('(?<![0-9]{2}):\s*|,|\n', values)
```

It separates by

- colons with optional spaces when they are not preceded by digits
- `,`
- `\n`

So `:` is a separator (when not preceded by a pair of digits). But so is `:`  or `:`   (still, when they are not preceded by a pair of digits). Consequence is that if, as it is the case if your string, there is a space after a colon, then that space is not included in the next field (since it is part of the separator, not of a field)

Or, you could also keep the first version of my answer (without `\s*`) and just `.strip()` the fields.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. How do I remove the white space it leaves behind because of '\n'. I got ['City','hell',' Country','rome',' Update date', '2022-09-26 00:00:00'] with your code instead of ['City','hell','Country','rome','Update date', '2022-09-26 00:00:00']

Comment: @MustaphaUnubiMomoh It is not because of ``\n``, but because there is a whitespace in your message. If you want trailing white space after colon to be ignore, you can add them to the separator regex. I edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Solution without `re`:

```py
values = "City:hell\nCountry:rome\nUpdate date: 2022-09-26 00:00:00"

out = [
    v.strip()
    for l in (line.split(":", maxsplit=1) for line in values.splitlines())
    for v in l
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['City', 'hell', 'Country', 'rome', 'Update date', '2022-09-26 00:00:00']
```

Answer (score 2):

What about doing a negative lookahead and look behind for digits?

something like..

```
re.split("(?<![0-9]):(?![0-9])|\n", values)
```

This will work so long as you don't have a key with numbers and a value with numbers.

Comment: Surrounding the `:` with `()` will cause the captured `:` to be added to the result list, which is probably not wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can split with a regex where the colon is matched only when not in between digits:

```py
re.split(r'[,\n]|:(?!(?<=\d.)\d)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrMelJ/3). Here, `[,\n]|:(?!(?<=\d.)\d)` matches a comma, a newline char, or a colon that is not immediately followed with a digit that is immediately preceded with a digit and any char (here, `:`).

You can match and *extract* the time pattern - `\b(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d\b` - or any char other than a newline, colon and comma one or more times:

```py
re.findall(r'(?:\b(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d\b|[^:,\n])+', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrMelJ/2).

*Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `\b(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d\b` - word boundary, a number from `0` to `23`, and then two occurrences of `:` char and a number from `0` to `59`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^:,\n]` - any char other than `:`, `,` and a newline
- `)+` - end of the grouping, one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
re.split(':(?!\d)|,|\n', values)
```

This says split by colon, only if not followed by a `/d`igit

Answer (score 1):

If all your time values are ##:##:## you can be extra careful to only replace that particular pattern, by using a substitute delimiter temporarily (as per my comment to your original question):

```
import re

values = 'City:hell\nCountry:rome\nUpdate date: 2022-09-26 12:34:56'

newvalues = re.sub(r"(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)",r"\1&\2&\3",values)

splitvalues = re.split(':|,|\n', newvalues)

splitsrepaired = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r"(\d\d)&(\d\d)&(\d\d)",r"\1:\2:\3",x),splitvalues))
```

splitsrepaired=['City', 'hell', 'Country', 'rome', 'Update date', ' 2022-09-26 12:34:56']

```
print(f"{splitsrepaired=}")
```